# Jetty recommended acceptor thread count

Tags: network-programming, jetty

Jetty recommends using a value of < 2 * available processors for the number of acceptor threads (both in its documentation and its behavior). What is the rationale for this recommendation? Is this recommendation specific to Jetty or is it a generally accepted best practice?